# Why couldn't Smith absorb Neo in The Matrix Reloaded?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Reloaded*, Agent Smith tries to absorb Neo, but fails. Why?

Comment: Because Neo resists him

Comment: Because it would make it too difficult to manufacture the merchandizing dolls.

Comment: Additional note: Smith only infects one other person who was jacking in, and it seems it was only as he was trying to leave the Matrix was at its weakest. And then Smith is surprised at the result. It may be that it's harder to infect those who are jacked in rather than running on the Machine's hardware. Or that the skills of the hackers help. Either way, the One would do better.

Answer (score 17):

Lots of spoilers here, so fair warning.

Neo is The One(tm). It connotes some mastery of The Matrix as a whole. Smith is able to absorb anyone and anything connected to The Matrix... except Neo, the "systemic anomaly". The movie heavily implies that Smith's very existence relies on Neo. Here's Smith himself

> **Smith:** Then you're aware of it.
>
> **Neo:** Of what?
>
> **Smith:** Our connection. I don't fully understand how it happened. Perhaps some part of you imprinted onto me, something overwritten or copied. That is at this point irrelevant, what matters is that whatever happened, happened for a reason.
>
> **Neo:** And what reason is that?
>
> **Smith:** I killed you, Mister Anderson, I watched you die... With a certain satisfaction, I might add, and then something happened. Something that I knew was impossible, but it happened anyway. You destroyed me, Mister Anderson. Afterward, I knew the rules, I understood what I was supposed to do but I didn't. I couldn't. I was compelled to stay, compelled to disobey. And now here I stand because of you, Mister Anderson, because of you I'm no longer an agent of the system, because of you I've changed - I'm unplugged - a new man, so to speak, like you, apparently free.

As long as Neo wants to exist, he cannot be forced to submit to Smith. That's the crux of the story. Consider this from *Reloaded*

> **The Oracle:** You have the sight now, Neo. You are looking at the world without time.
> **Neo:** Then why can’t I see what happens to her?
> **The Oracle:** We can never see past the choices we don’t understand.
> **Neo:** Are you saying I have to choose whether Trinity lives or dies?
> **The Oracle:** No. You’ve already made the choice, now you have to understand it.

This comes up again at the end of *Revolutions*, when Neo is facing Smith

> **Smith/Oracle:** Why, Mr. Anderson, why? Why, why do you do it? Why, why get up? Why keep fighting? Do you believe you’re fighting for something, for more than your survival? Can you tell me what it is, do you even know? Is it freedom or truth, perhaps peace – could it be for love? Illusions, Mr. Anderson, vagaries of perception. Temporary constructs of a feeble human intellect trying desperately to justify an existence that is without meaning or purpose. And all of them as artificial as the Matrix itself. Although, only a human mind could invent something as insipid as love. You must be able to see it, Mr. Anderson, you must know it by now! You can’t win, it’s pointless to keep fighting! Why, Mr. Anderson, why, why do you persist?
> **Neo:** Because I choose to.

Then The Oracle reaches out through Smith

> {Neo is knocked back against the crater wall and is lying on the ground}

> **Smith/Oracle:** Wait… I’ve seen this. This is it, this is the end. Yes, you were laying right there, just like that, and I… I… I stand here, right here, I’m… I’m supposed to say something. I say… Everything that has a beginning has an end, Neo.

This is the point where Neo realizes that he cannot win as The One, and must choose the path of sacrifice

> **Neo:** You were right, Smith. You were always right. It was inevitable.

Comment: 1.) Great answer. 2.) I fully read that with Smith's voice.

Answer (score 5):

We see (from the notes in the original screenplay) that Smith fails because Neo summons his will and prevents him from taking over his code, presumably by using '*the power of the one*' or somesuch.

> He stabs his hand into Neo, his fingers burying into Neo’s chest.
>
> **FIRST SMITH (CONT’D):** *Purpose.*
>
> The jolt of Smith sears into him, his code spreading like a
> cancer, metastasizing with binary speed.
>
> Stunned, Neo looks down at the darkness that begins to cover
> him.
>
> INT. NEBUCHADNEZZAR - MAIN DECK – DAY
> Link tries to translate the code that is describing what it
> can't describe.
>
> TRINITY: *What is happening to him?*
>
> LINK *I don't know.*
>
> EXT. TENEMENT PARK – DAY
> Neo begins to panic, fear clouds his eyes.
>
> AGENT SMITH: *Yes, that's it. It will be over soon*.
>
> **Focusing the entirety of his will, Neo slowly takes hold of
> Smith's arm.**
> **The Smiths all look at each other, simultaneously, equally experiencing the same disbelief.**
> **The blackness spreading like liquid obsidian suddenly stops as Neo summons a final surge and shaking from the effort,**
> **rips the fingers from his chest—**
> **Severing the connection, the darkness instantly evaporating.**
>
> <sub><sup>[The Matrix Reloaded - Screenplay](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/scripts/the-matrix-reloaded-2003.pdf)</sup></sub>

Comment: I always thought it was just because he removed the arm using his bare hands.

Comment: @Clockwork Those can go together. He's the One, so he can resist with enough strength to stop the attack. And the physical manifestation of this is that he's able to move Smith's arm (the attack vector) out from his chest. Or maybe he maintained enough physical strength and control in the Matrix world to be able to pull his arm out, unlike everyone else who would have been taken out.